# How to go on after vims bracket autocomplete

Tags: vim

I have mapped this feature where I put any bracket and vim autocompletes the second bracket and places the cursor inside the brackets so I can fill it. Now, does anyone of you have an idea how to avoid always hitting ESC and navigating outside the bracket again after finishing the text inside? How do you handle "skipping" the closing bracket?

Comment: Either by pressing the right arrow or, if your autoclosing plugin has that feature, by typing the closing characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell `vim` not to auto complete by  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>  -  <kbd>v</kbd>  before typing the bracket.

Or as  <kbd>-></kbd>  or plugin dependent as suggested by `romainl`